# Can I use pyglet with python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyglet

I'm new to python and I would like to experiment with pyglet. I am using python 3.4, but it seems that pyglet only supports python to version 3.3 . Can I still use the 3.3 version , or will I have compatibility issues?

Comment: Please ask only one question by question.